# iText 7 converting HTML to PDF - How to see entire wide table?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, pdfhtml

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/very-wide-table_01.html");
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(is, os);
```

When input HTML has a wide table, this message is seen (and the table is truncated, data is lost):

> WARN  TableWidths   Table width is more than expected due to min width of cell(s).

How can I tell iText to either scale the content to fit the PDF page, OR scale the page to fit the content?

I'm sure this can be done with PDF. The Aspose.PDF library does it by default. But I need a way to do it with iText.

(edit) It's any table too wide for the PDF page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/XHTML">
<head><title>very wide table</title><meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <style>
    table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    table, td, th {border: 1px solid red;}
    th {text-align: center; text-weight: bold;}
  </style></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><td colspan="30">Very wide table</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
    <td>1234567890</td><td>1234567890</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the table (HTML) you're trying to convert?

Comment: what would be the expected behavior here for you? a smaller font? more rows? a wider PDF document?

Comment: Desired outcome might be scaling the content to fit the page, or scaling the page to fit the content. Whether that means changing the overall dots per inch, or "wider document", whatever.   Just changing font size alone wouldn't change the spacing within and around the table, unless you mean to include all that too. Moving columns to rows would be changing the table. Don't change the table. I need the original rows and columns preserved.

Comment: changing the size of the document it is! convertPdf can also take `PdfDocument` as an argument, and you can define in there the size of the output PDF document

Comment: @AndréLemos I haven't yet been able to make that work. I've tried several other things also. There is mention of chaning DPI via one of the properties, but I just get the same thing.

Comment: can you show how you tried to change the size if the output PDF document by using the `PdfDocument` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

This answers the basic question of how to change page size to account for very large tables. This answer does *not* provide any means of determining the required width, but at least this code does change the default page size.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
doc.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(2000, 200));
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/very-wide-table_01.html"), doc, props);
```